# Multi-line fading ellipsis in a TextView

Tags: android, textview

I can make a multi-line TextView whose text is truncated with an ellipsis by setting android:ellipsize="end", and I can make a single-line TextView whose text fades out by setting android:ellipsize="marquee". But the marquee setting doesn't work when there's more than one line in the TextView.

Is there any way to truncate text by fading out the last line in a multi-line TextView?

Edit: I'm able to do a sort of hacky implementation using two separate TextViews, and adding an OnLayoutChangeListener to the first to check if the text will exceed X number of lines, then cutting the text off there and putting the remainder into the second TextView, which is limited to one line and thus able to fade out using ellipsize=marquee.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_two"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
/>
```

```java
mTextOne = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_one);
mTextTwo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_two);

mTextOne.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right,
            int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        if (mTextOne.getLineCount() > 4) {
            int start = mTextOne.getLayout().getLineStart(3);
            String twoText = mTextOne.getText().toString().substring(start);
            mTextTwo.setText(twoText);
            mTextOne.setMaxLines(3);
        }
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, I was hoping to implement this for every item in a list, and I can't find a way to do that. I've only gotten this to work for the case of two simple TextViews on a static page.